# Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:sqlite3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm learning to create API's using Python [here](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/build-an-api-under-30-lines-of-code-with-python-and-flask/). I've gotten everything ready and downloaded the database, however when I run my app I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    e = create_engine("sqlite3:///salaries.db")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 56, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 139, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 212, in load
    (self.group, name))
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:sqlite3
```

What am I doing wrong to where it will not load the correct plugin?

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps


e = create_engine("sqlite3:///salaries.db")

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class DepartmentsMeta(Resource):
    def get(self):
        conn = e.connect()
        query = conn.execute("select distinct DEPARTMENT from salaries")
        return {"departments": [i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]}


class DepartmentSalary(Resource):
    def get(self, department_name):
        conn = e.connect()
        query = conn.execute("select * from salaries where Department='%s'" % department_name)
        result = {"data": [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i))] for i in query.cursor}
        return result


api.add_resource(DepartmentSalary, "/dept/<string:department_name>")
api.add_resource(DepartmentsMeta, "/department")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please try replacing this line:

```
e = create_engine("sqlite3:///salaries.db")
```

with

```
e = create_engine("sqlite:///salaries.db")
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem. I've solved it by:

`pip3 uninstall flask_sqlalchemy` and `pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy==2.5.1` because big changes with `flask-sqlalchemy==3.0` SQLite DB in memory are not set as default in this version.

Hope it helps you.